# Need help with the fine details of tiling a shower niche

Tags: tile

I installed a 14x22 prefabbed plastic niche for my shower renovation. It is made by EZ Niche. I am using 4x12 ceramic picket tiles for the walls. For the inside edges of the niche, I bought some 4x16 subway tiles that I will trim to fit. I am using Schluter jolly trim mitered for the inside corners. The back wall of the niche will be tiled with glass pebble mosaic pieces.

I have a few trivial questions regarding the fine details of how to tile the niche:

1. Should I complete the wall tile installation completely before installing the niche tile or should the niche be tiled in at the same time as the walls?
2. Should the mosaic back wall of the niche be installed before or after installing the inside edge subway tiles + schluter trim?
3. Does the schluter trim need to be installed first, waiting 1 day for the thinset to cure, prior to installing the niche inside edge tiles? Or should they be installed at the same time?
4. Referencing the picture below:

   1. should the schluter jolly be pushed out to be flush with the adjacent wall tile (labeled A) or should the jolly stick out further than the tile?
   2. Should the wall tile mating to the bottom of the niche (labeled B in picture below) be cut flush with the bottom edge of the niche or should I trim it by 1 grout line width to have a grout line between the schluter trim and the tile edge? I was also thinking to use wedge spacers along the jolly to create a grout line between the jolly and the niche itself
   3. Should the inside edge subway tile have a tight fit to one another or should I account for a grout line on each end where the tiles meet? (labeled C in picture below)

[image]

5. What kind of tile should I use to tile across the face of the shelf? I want to lay 1 continuous tile across the width of the shelf. The length of the niche is 14" so my picket tiles don't span the entire width of the shelf. I have the 16" long subway tiles that I can trim to size, however they are not as thick as the picket tiles and wouldn't be flush with the wall tile. What should I use to tile the face of the shelf?

[image]

Comment: If the subway tile is installed first, its face doesn't interface well with the bumpy lines you get by cutting a sheet of irregular glass mosaic. You would have to cut some glass tiles if you want tiny caulk beads. You want tiny caulk beads back there. By doing the mosaic first you can fit the subway tile up against the surface, mark any high spots, and trim your subway tile to fit around the glass.

Comment: For the face of the shelf, continue the zigzag with the pickets. I think there'll be a bit of the vertical edge showing down low, where that's not ideal, but a monolithic piece across the face will be 100 times worse. And if there's the tiniest color mismatch? O.M.G. I consider that bit of vertical edge down low a deal killer for contrasting grout, I think. I'd have to actually see the zigzag pre-grout.

Comment: You've got EIGHT separate questions here. While it's commonly acceptable at many places online, that's far too broad for this site. Please take the [tour] to see how things work here, then [edit] this down to just _one_ question. Feel free to [ask all the followup  questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of questions, and many of them are aesthetic so don't have correct answers.  But here's one suggestion:  Instead of using that plastic shelf and having to tile it on three sides, buy a piece of plain white marble that is the length and depth of that shelf but a little thinner, in a color similar to your tiles, lay your tile round the three sides of the niche up to the level of the shelf, and lay the marble shelf on the tile edges.  Then tile up to the top of the niche.  It'll look nicer than a fussy tiled shelf and save you a lot of unrewarding work tiling the shelf.   You don't need the corner bead along the marble shelf.